# Error while trying to install cpulimit on centos 8

Tags: centos, cpulimit

```
[root@XYZ ~]# sudo dnf install cpulimit
Last metadata expiration check: 0:17:21 ago on Tue 13 Oct 2020 11:24:25 AM PDT.
No match for argument: cpulimit
Error: Unable to find a match: cpulimit
[root@XYZ ~]#
```

Unable to find a resolution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 1) Don't use `sudo` if you are logged in as `root`.  2) if even without `sudo` you still have an issue, tell us what you get from `dnf list | grep cpulimit` and  also `dnf search cpulimit ` ?

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
rpm -ivh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
dnf install cpulimit
```

Should work.

`cpulimit` is not part of the official CentOS repository, you've got to enable EPEL for that: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

Comment: I can't reach that URL.[root@XYZ ~]# rpm -ivh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
Retrieving https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
error: skipping https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm - transfer failed
[root@XYZ ~]# curl https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
[root@XYZ ~]#

Comment: Also I do not see support for EDEL 8 on https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/cpulimit.

Comment: You've got connectivity issues. The file downloads just fine for me. I don't understand why you're checking the fedora project web page when you're running CentOS 8.